# launching release iOS app not downloading to multiple device when using .ipa file via url in flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store, ipa

I am building a flutter app and I want to public ios using .ipa file which is going to be downloaded via URL

After creating the .ipa file and use the URL to download, it only works with my device (iPhone ios 12.3.1). In other devices, it just stopped downloading at the end.

Steps used to create the .ipa file and the URL:

- using flutter command to build a release ios (flutter build ios --release)
- archive it using XCode 10.2.1
- export .ipa file using Adhoc (I am using individual apple developer membership)
- using this site (https://www.diawi.com/) to create the URL

The libraries used is:

- flutter_bloc: ^0.17.0
- firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+6
- cloud_firestore: ^0.12.5
- firebase_storage: ^3.0.1
- firebase_messaging: ^5.0.3
- intl: ^0.15.8
- cached_network_image: ^1.0.0

Comment: You can't simply sideload iOS apps. You might want to familiarize yourself with the way how Apple allows app distribution, e.g. https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204270118-iOS-Creating-an-App-Store-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile

Comment: Thanks Max for your respond